# How do you disable the admin-bar.css

Tags: admin-bar

I don't want to fully disable the admin bar. I just want to remove its css file so I can fully customize it myself without having to override anything with greater selectors or a load of `!important`

The exact file name that is being loaded is `admin-bar.min.css` and then along with the Wordpress version `?ver=[...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Should do the  trick

```
<?php 
function adminBar_dequeue() {
    wp_dequeue_style('admin-bar');
    wp_deregister_style('admin-bar');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adminBar_dequeue', 9999 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'adminBar_dequeue', 9999 ); 

?>
```